# comparing two date objects of different formats

Tags: java, date, selenium, time, comparison

I have two dates.

The first date is the system time.  The second date is related to a news article and when the article expires, it is called end_time.

Im using selenium to test that the article does in fact expire when the system time exceed the the end_time.

My code is as follows:

```
String searchstring = poriginal;
//make objects to be compared
Date parsed_system_time=null;
Date parsed_end_time=null;

//generate a current time object    
GenerateSimpleTime current_time = new GenerateSimpleTime();
current_time.setSystem_time_snapshot();
String system_time = current_time.getSystem_time_snapshot();


//set up the SimpleDateFormat to be used for parsing the strings into objects for comparison
//parsing the date format e.g : 04:11:2016 11:34 AM
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm");
try{
    System.out.println("Trying to parse system time: \n");
    parsed_system_time = sdf.parse(system_time);
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    System.out.println("Couldnt parse system time...\n");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat end_time_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm a");
try {
    parsed_end_time = end_time_sdf.parse(end_date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldnt parse end_date...\n");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(parsed_system_time.before(parsed_end_time))
{
current_time.setSystem_time_snapshot();
try {
    system_time = current_time.getSystem_time_snapshot();
    parsed_system_time = sdf.parse(system_time);
    System.out.println("endtime is: "+ parsed_end_time+"\n");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldnt parse current_time.getSystem_time_snapshot()...\n");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//System.out.println("system time is: \n");
}
```

When i run the program the dates are in the following format

endtime: Fri Nov 04 13:49:00 AEST 2016

systemtime: 04:11:2016 1:52 PM

if it a problem when comparing the two dates if they are in a different format.  It shouldn't matter right?

When I run the test my program goes and runs indefinitely and doesnt detect when system time is greater than the end time.

The setSystem_time_snapshot() does the following:

```
 String pattern= "dd:MM:YYY h:mm a";
     SimpleDateFormat simpletime = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
     system_time_snapshot = simpletime.format(new Date());

     System.out.println("system time snapshop is "+system_time_snapshot+"\n");
```

Any ideas where I clean up this mess and get it working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `setSystem_time_snapshot()` is returning a string in the format of

```
dd:MM:YYY h:mm a
```

But your sdf is

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm");
```

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat thanks for your input.  I did try your suggestion but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: what exactly is the issue, is some exception being thrown?

Comment: There is no exception being thrown,  the while loop never terminates: system time snapshop is 04:11:2016 2:23 PM

endtime is: Fri Nov 04 14:22:00 AEST 2016

Comment: I tried to add the timezone to the sdf  and the setSytem_time method "dd:MM:YYY h:mm a z" but it didnt resolve the issue

Comment: change YYY to yyyy

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScareyWombat that seemed to do it.  Why is it that changing the year format made it work?  I would think that that would not be an issue?

Comment: bause your `setSystem_time_snapshot` is returning a String based upon this erroneous format - To be honest, why not just return a Date?

Comment: You are right I should change that.  I am a novice programmer so please excuse my code.  To be honest I made a bit of a dogs dinner of this by having this system date generator in a separate class.  Hopefully I can learn to program in a better way.  I appreciate your help looking at those dates was beginning to exhaust me.

Comment: "To be honest, why not just return a Date":  Do you mean just return simpletime.  from SimpleDateFormat simpletime = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);?

Answer (score 0):

If you endtime is: Fri Nov 04 13:49:00 AEST 2016,
you should use "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy" in your SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat end_time_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Kevin. I managed to get it working thanks.  I didn't see your post.  I didn't realise that the format would mess up my test.  Thanks for responding.